# how to change value of properties with signal

Tags: reactjs, signals

I have the following react code:

```
import { signal } from '@preact/signals';

...
    const initalRequest: IRequest = {
    "SiteDisplayName": "Something",
    "SiteName": "",
    "SiteDescription": "",
    "SiteMembers": [],
    "SiteOwner": "",
    "Sitetype": SiteTypes.WithoutTeams,
  };
  const siteRequest = signal(initalRequest);

  const onTextFieldChange = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newText: string): void => {
    //console.log('onTextFieldChange', ev.currentTarget.id);
    switch (ev.currentTarget.id) {
      case "Name": siteRequest.value.SiteName = newText; break; // remove spaces .split(' ').join('') 
      case "SiteDisplayName" : siteRequest.value.SiteDisplayName = newText; break;
      case "SiteDescription" : siteRequest.value.SiteDescription = newText; break;    
      default:break;
    }
    
    // Case "" :siteRequest.value.SiteOwner = "";
  };

  return (
    <section className={`${styles.createNoProjectSite} ${hasTeamsContext ? styles.teams : ''}`}>
      <h2>Well done, {escape(userDisplayName)}!</h2>
      <TextField id='Name' label="Site Name" value={siteRequest.value.SiteName} onChange={onTextFieldChange}       />
      <TextField id='SiteDisplayName' label="Site Display Name" value={siteRequest.value.SiteName} onChange={onTextFieldChange}       />
      <TextField id='SiteDescription' label="Site Description" value={siteRequest.value.SiteName} onChange={onTextFieldChange}  multiline={true}     />
      <div>{siteRequest.value.SiteDescription}</div>
      <br />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(siteRequest.value, null, 2)}</pre>
    </section>
```

there are no errors but the value of the object "siteRequest" never changes.
the syntax "siteRequest.value.SiteName = newText;" is wrong or preact signal does not work with objects outside of arrays.

anyone can show my the light? :-) can "[deepsignal](https://github.com/EthanStandel/deepsignal#deepsignalcore)" be the answer?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure, I'm one of the maintainers.

The issue you're running into is that you're setting the signal value to an object, then mutating that object's properties -- these properties are not themselves signals. For signals to update you need to assign to the signal's `value` property directly.

Signals do not offer deep reactivity out-of-the-box for a variety of technical reasons.

You can indeed use one of the libraries that wraps Signals to add deep reactivity, or simply alter your code to mutate the entire object, i.e.:

```js
case "Name":
    siteRequest.value = { ...siteRequest.value, SiteName: newText };
    break;
```